# Symfony2 handle jQuery serialized Form and extra data sent with ajax post

Tags: ajax, symfony

I'm trying to handle the form and some extra data sent with ajax.

Here is my ajax post code :

```
$(document).on('submit', '#edit-entreprise', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $entreprise = $("#liste-entreprises").val();
        var $url = Routing.generate('load_edit_entreprise_form');
        var $formSerialize = $('#edit-entreprise').serialize() + "&entreprise=" + $entreprise;
        $(".panel-entreprise").empty().append('<div class="progress"> <div class="indeterminate"></div> </div>');
        $.ajax({
            url: $url,
            type: 'POST',
            data: $formSerialize,
            success: function(html) {
                console.log(html);
            }
        });
    });
```

And here, my controler :

```
public function editAction(Request $request)
    {
        $entreprise = $request->request->get('entreprise');
        $entreprise = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('AvisClientsBundle:Entreprise')
            ->find($entreprise);

        $editForm = $this->createForm('AvisClientsBundle\Form\EntrepriseType', $entreprise);
        $editForm->handleRequest($request);

        if ($editForm->isSubmitted() && $editForm->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($entreprise);
            $em->flush();

            return new Response(json_encode(array('status' => 'success')));
        }
        return new Response(json_encode($this->render('AvisClientsBundle:Admin/Entreprise:edit.html.twig', array(
            'entreprise' => $entreprise,
            'edit_form' => $editForm->createView(),
        ))->getContent()));
    }
```

I don't know how to receive the form and the extra data :(

Can you explain me how to do this ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I do it like this :

Ajax (I use [FormData](http://www.javascripture.com/FormData) ):

```
$('#formId').submit(function (event) {
        // Eviter le comportement par défaut (soumettre le formulaire)
        event.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this);

        $.ajax({
            url: $this.attr('action'),
            type: $this.attr('method'),
            data: new FormData($this[0]),
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            error: function (request, status, error) {
                callback(request.responseText);
            },
            complete: function () {
                //
            },
            statusCode: {
                //traitement en cas de succès
                200: function (response) {
                    var message = response.message;
                    callback(response, event);
                },
                412: function (response, event) {
                    callback(response);
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

In sf2 here is the handler:

```
public function updateAction(Request $request, $id) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entity = $em->getRepository('testBundle:testEntity')->find($id);
        if (!$entity) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find  entity.');
        }
        $editForm = $this->createEditForm($entity);
        $editForm->handleRequest($request);

        if ($editForm->isValid()) {
            $em->flush();
            //envoi des données JSON en front
            $response = new JsonResponse();
            $response->setStatusCode(200);
            //ajout de données éventuelles
            $response->setData(array(
                'message' => "Ligne buffer updated",
                'form' => json_encode($this->getHtmlForm($entity))));
            return $response;
        } else {
            //form non valide
            //envoi des données d'erreurs JSON en front
            $response = new JsonResponse();
            $response->setStatusCode(412);
            $response->setData(array(
                'form' => json_encode($this->getHtmlForm($entity)),
                'message' => $editForm->getErrorsAsString(),
            ));
            return $response;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hello, Thank for your answer. I know how to post a form sent with ajax. But i need to share extra data to my controller.  What I want is to read the additional data that is the id of my object and read data from my form that are data from my object.